# Visual Studio 2012 cout not shown but cerr

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cout

I switched my IDE from **VS 2008** to **VS 2010**. Now I'm getting some strange behaviour with `cout`.

My solution consists of an exe and several dlls which are linked to.

When I call `std::cout` in the exe project, everthing is shown on the console window as well as `std::cerr`.

If I call `std::cout` inside a dll, nothing is printed out to the console. If I call the same with `std::cerr` the output is shown on the console window.

This issues didn't appear in VS 2008. Anyone seen such issue before?

**Update:**
I tried the following:

`std::cerr << "Hello World!"  << std::endl;
    std::printf("Hello World!2\n");
    std::clog << "Hello World!3" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World!4"  << std::endl;`

The output is like:

    `Hello World!
    Hello World!2
    Hello World!3`

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't changed anything.

Comment: Were all the dlls built with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Yes, all the dlls were build with VS 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, drescherjm was right.

I still linked to the VS9 version 3rd party library (OpenCV 2.4.2). That caused the issues.

When I did the following:

`std::clog << "diff = " << cv::Mat(diff) << std::endl;`

It resulted in the following output:

`diff =`

After that line of code, no more output was generated. So something happend inside the OpenCV code. After linking to the correct version (unfortunately there were no errors/warnings before), everything is fine again.

Thanks for your help!